# Typescript for newbies: can be typeA or typeB situation

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and I did search SO / Google for a comprehensive explanation for my problem here but I didn't find satisfactory answer (or I don't yet understand what that all means like here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

My simple example is that I have an interface whose property can be a string (initially) and then such interface changes to feature other type (from string to object).

So here is what happens:

```
export interface SnippetSetReceivedFromServer {
    title: string,
    snippets: Array<string>
}

export interface SnippetSetTransformedByClient {
    title: string,
    snippets: Array<{ _id: string, sanitizedLocalThumbnail: SafeUrl }>
}
```

first time I receive data from the server it has data shape with array of strings, then this snippet set object gets image url and its data shape changes.

So if I would want to have just a type that sort of works for both I would use 'any':

```
export interface GenericSnippetSet {
    title: string,
    snippets: Array<any>
}
```

But why cant I use this approach:

```
export interface SnippetSet {
    title: string,
    expanded?: boolean,
    snippets: Array<string | { _id: string, sanitizedLocalThumbnail: SafeUrl }>
}
```

I am confused because I am sure I saw examples where people are using "either or" approach with typescript but its hard for me to find a clue of when (in practical sense) that is OK and when it should not be used?

For now I stick to "any" in the app and its fine, but I would want to understand this nuance better.

Comment: What's preventing you from using that approach? Error? if so post it.

Comment: "Why can't I use this approach?"  You can, if you want... maybe you should put more code showing how you want to use it so people can advise you.  Right now all I can say is that `SnippetSet` might be a wider type than you want, since it can represent values you won't have.  But that is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: But why do you want to use a single interface for two different things in the first place?

Comment: ops yeah this is a good thought indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally want to disallow values that would not be valid. Your version would allow invalid values. You might consider this approach:

```
export interface SnippetSet<T> {
  title: string,
  expanded?: boolean,
  snippets: Array<T>
}
```

Where you can now parameterize at call-site or through an alias:

```
type GenericSnippetSet = SnippetSet<string>
type SnippetTransformed = SnippetSet<{ _id: string, ... }>
```

Edit: A good use for union types is where any version of the union is valid and you intend to handle all of the versions at runtime, through some conditional code (switch statement probably).

Comment: I see so the core principle is kind of not to do those "either or" as the whole idea is to type things precisely? Your answer is very helpful as a solution, but can you help understand in which cases having prop: <typeA | typeB> is allowed? what should I have it for?